# Redirect from beta to production site

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, seo

I have a beta site on a subdomain and I'm ready to move the site from the subdomain to the production site.
Google has already indexed some of the beta pages and they are coming up in search results. I want to redirect from the beta site to the production URL and return a 302 code to Google, in order to retain the links. What would be the best way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What web server are you on?  If you want only the production site to show up in Google search results, you will actually want to send 301 return codes (permanent redirects) in order to keep your page rank for the prod site.  Perform a search on this site (or your favorite search engine) for either 'mod_rewrite rules' (Apache) or 'iis url rewrite'.  Should turn up with plenty of ideas on how to setup your redirects.  You for sure want to send the 301 response code though in order to keep your page rank with the prod site.

Comment: Agreed - 301 is the best response to return for SEO. 302 usually means "please log in first" and a lot of engines won't follow a 302.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm on IIS (Tagged it :)) any specific advice?